# delete[] in destructor

Tags: c++, templates, destructor, delete-operator

Well, I'm studying templates and, I have a problem with the next code:

```
        #include <iostream>

        using namespace std;

        template<class T, int n>
        class Table
        {
        public:
            Table();
            //~Table();
            int& operator[](int i);
            bool Resize(int n);
            int Count();
            void Free();

        private:
            T* inst;
            int count;
        };

        template<class T, int n>
        Table<T, n>::Table()
        {
            inst = new T[n];
            count = n;
        }

        template<class T, int n>
        void Table<T, n>::Free()
        {
            delete[] this->inst;
        }

        template<class T, int n>
        int& Table<T, n>::operator[](int i)
        {
            return inst[i];
        } 

        template<class T, int n>
        bool Table<T, n>::Resize(int n)
        {
            this->inst = (T*)realloc(this->inst, sizeof(T)*count + sizeof(T)*n);
            if(!inst)
                return false;

            return true;
        }

        template<class T, int n>
        int Table<T, n>::Count()
        {
            return this->count;
        }

        template<typename T, int n> void ShowTable(Table<T, n> t)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<t.Count(); i++)
                cout<<t[i]<<endl;
        }

        int main()
        {
            Table<int, 2> table;
            table[0] = 23;
            table[1] = 150;
            ShowTable(table);

            system("pause");
            table.Free();

            return 0;
        }
```

It works but, when I put the `delete[] this->inst;` in the destructor, it throws me an Assertion Failed, and I don't know why... I mean, is it bad to delete resources in a destructor?

Answer (score 1):

You have a duplicate identifier `n` in the following method definition:

```
    template<class T, int n>
    bool Table<T, n>::Resize(int n)
```

I got an error compiling with the above declaration, I'm surprised you didn't. You will want to rename one of the `int n` to something else (such as `Resize(int newsize)`).

There is no problem with deleting your `inst` member in the destructor. That is what you should be doing to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Thank you but I changed the name of that parameter and I still get that assertation failed when i write: delete[] this->inst; in the definition of the destructor

Comment: Your code worked for me after changing the name of the parameter. What's the actual message you get? (Assertion failed messages usually come with *some* detail)

Comment: It throws me "Expression _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)" dbgdel.cpp line: 52

Comment: I realised that the problem is in the ShowTable method (because if I show the table values with cout at the main method the error doesn't appear) but I don't know where it's wrong

Comment: I see the problem. You are passing your table to `ShowTable()` by value, but you have not defined a suitable copy constructor for your `Table` class. Because you have a plain pointer in your class, you *must* define a copy constructor (and assignment operator) which makes a copy of the `inst` data. To see the problem, set a breakpoint on your destructor and see how many times it tries to delete the same block of memory.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I solved the problem changing the parameter of ShowTable from "Table<T, n> t" to "Table<T, n> &t"